# Selenium: complex XPath example

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I need to locate a node with XPath in Selenium code for automation.
The problem is that the node needs to be selected does not contain the information for identification, but another node which is descendant of a parent node of the target node does.

```
<object>...</object>

<object>
    <div>Name</div>
    <target></target>
</object>

<object>...</object>
```

To simplify the situation it looks like above. There are multiple "object" nodes and only distinguished from each other by "Name". While we can't use parenthesis in XPath, how can I select that node with `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the following XPath expression may be what you're looking for:

```
//div[text()="Name"]/../target
```

This essentially targets a `div` with text content `Name`, steps up to its parent with `..` and then selects children of node type `target`.

If the `target` node is not an immediate child of the parent, the following will look for `target` nodes that are descendants of the parent at any depth (note the only difference is there are now two slashes in front of `target`):

```
//div[text()="Name"]/..//target
```

Comment: I think it's the right approach, but what should I do if the 'target' is at deep down in 'object'?

    //div[text()="Name"]/../

This part is good, but what can I do if substructure of the object is too complicated and even random? Can you consider the 'target' as a child of 'object'??

Comment: Ok, first of all, I appreciate your interest. Now I can clarify my question. 'Name' is also located deep down from object. Therefore, it needs to be considered as a descendant of the object. In other words, /../ can't locate the proper object. Let's consider <object>...</object> is <div class="object">...</div>, and the class name is a clue to find 'object' from a lot of ancestors of 'Name'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want do generic function and want pass your parameter every time.Try this.

```
def fxpath(varstring):
    Xpathelement = "//div[text()='{}']/../target".format(varstring)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(Xpathelement)

fxpath('Name')
```